# Crystal Reports - Assign a count value to a specific record value

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am afer some help, I am a newbie with Crystal Reports (have been asked to use at my new work to update some reports printed)

We print out a lot of labels for parts and each part is assigned to a Job number. ((each job number can have multiple parts, and so there are numerous records sharing the same Job number)
currently the part label prints out the job number from within the database, however I am wanting to convert these to just a Location Number (1,2,3,4,5 etc..) so that each specific job number in the database is assigned a Location number, and this is then printed instead of the Job number. (The Labels are a subreport from a main report that selects a new label for each record in the database table.)

Long winded explenation and probably not very clear, but hopefully someone understands and can explain how I can achieve this simply using Crystal Reports .

Thanks in advance.

Im not sure where to start on this

Comment: This is indeed not very clear. Please specify the problem. For example, are you asking about adding information to the database? Or is it about getting existing information out of the database. Either way, more concrete details are needed.